# Are there any functions that are differentiable on on $(a,b)$ and such that $f(a)=f(b)$ but do not follow Rolle's theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, Rolle's Theorem requires three conditions:

$(i) f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

$(ii)$ $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$

$(iii)$ $f(a)=f(b)$

So I am trying to show that all three conditions are necessary for Rolle's theorem to apply, but I have been unable to come up with a function that meets $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ but there does not exist a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$

Any thoughts? For the other two condition combinations I came up with

for $(i$) and $(ii)$ $f(x)=x$,

and $(i)$ and $(iii)$ $f(x)=|x|$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On $[0,1]$, try $$f(x) = \cases{x & if $x < 1$\cr
                                0 & if $x = 1$\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ f(x)=x$ from $0 < x \leq 1$ and $f(0)=1$